# jquery validate is working on some fields

Tags: html, wordpress, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate in wordpress comments for error message. I've four fields 3 text, 1 textarea. one of the 3 text field is email. Problem is, only textarea and email field is showing error messages but other two is doing nothing 
and let me submit the form without those.

```
<form action="url/to/the/site/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate="novalidate"><div id="wdpajax-info"></div>
                <p>Su dirección de correo electrónico no será publicada. Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios</p><div class="nz-clearfix"></div><p class="respond-textarea"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true" cols="58" rows="10" tabindex="4" class="error" aria-invalid="true"></textarea></p><p class="comment-form-author"><input class="ninzio-placeholder required valid" id="opinion_title11" name="opinion_title11" type="text" tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Opinion title *" value="Opinion title *" size="30" aria-required="true"></p>
<p class="comment-form-author"><input class="ninzio-placeholder required valid" id="author11" name="author11" type="text" tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Name *" value="Name *" size="30" aria-required="true"></p>
<p class="comment-form-email"><input class="ninzio-placeholder required error" id="email" name="email" type="text" tabindex="2" data-placeholder="E-Mail *" value="E-Mail *" size="30" aria-required="true"></p>
        <!-- CRFP Fields: Start -->
        <p class="crfp-field">
                        <span class="star-rating-control"><div class="rating-cancel" style="display: block;"><a title="Cancel">0</a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live"><a title="1">1</a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live"><a title="2">2</a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live"><a title="3">3</a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live"><a title="4">4</a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live"><a title="5">5</a></div></span><input name="rating-star" type="radio" class="star star-rating-applied" value="1" style="display: none;">
            <input name="rating-star" type="radio" class="star star-rating-applied" value="2" style="display: none;">
            <input name="rating-star" type="radio" class="star star-rating-applied" value="3" style="display: none;">
            <input name="rating-star" type="radio" class="star star-rating-applied" value="4" style="display: none;">
            <input name="rating-star" type="radio" class="star star-rating-applied" value="5" style="display: none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="crfp-rating" value="0">
        </p>
        <!-- CRFP Fields: End -->
        <p class="form-submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Enviar"> <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="11458" id="comment_post_ID">
<input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
</p>            </form>
```

jquery file is as follow:

```
commentform.validate({
        rules: {
            // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
            comment:{required:true},
            // compound rule
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            opinion_title11: {required:true},
            author11: {required:true},
        },
        messages: {
            // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
            comment:"Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios.",
            opinion_title11: "Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios.",
            author11: "Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios.",
            // compound rule
            email: "La dirección de email debe contener @."
        },
submitHandler: function(form){
other validation codes.
}
});
```

I've found different issues and solution and most of them are because of name fields, required fields, input tag incorrect format. but i don't find any of this in my codes. I tried to with changed name and order of the text field but no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you,

---

### UPDATED

Just discovered another strange functionality. When I press backspace on the empty text field that are not working while submitting showing the error message that I want to show when user try to send a empty text field.

Comment: Which line is the error on? Check out the console on your browser, under the errors tab.

Comment: @Rigidity - error is on author11 and opinion_title11.

Answer (score 0):

Well after few more experiment I've found the issue.
It's placeholder which is creating the problem.

jquery validate by default can't ignore placeholder. If there is a placeholder in any field validate things this placeholder as a value and never throws an empty field error. 
To solve this error I've added following javascript just before the form.validate{} starts. This will add a method to the validator plugin to avoid placeholders value. And also don't forget to add the method name as true in the rules. Codes are bellow:

```
$.validator.addMethod("placeholder", function (value, element) {
        if (value == $(element).attr('data-placeholder')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And the rules array is:

```
rules: {
            // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
            comment: {required: true, placeholder: true},
            // compound rule
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                placeholder: true
            },
            opinion_title: {required: true, placeholder: true},
            author: {required: true, placeholder: true}
        },
```

That solved my problem. Hope it'll help others too.

Thank you for all your effort to help to solve my issues.